# I have to enter my login twice and ssh-key doesn't work on a dockerized gitlab

Tags: docker, nginx, gitlab

I launch gitlab with this command:

```
sudo docker run --detach --hostname example.com --publish 4433:443 --publish 8080:80 --publish 2222:22 --name gitlab --restart always --volume /data/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab --volume /data/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab --volume /data/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest
```

`example.com` being another URL, as you may have guessed.

I have an nginx server with this config:

```
server {
  server_name example.com;
  client_max_body_size 50m;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote-addr;
  }
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate [MY PATH TO THE .pem FILE];
  ssl_certificate_key [OTHER PATH];
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
  if ($host = example.com) {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
  }
}
```

When I use HTTPS to clone and push repos, I have to enter my login/password twice, and when I use ssh (for example `git clone git@example.com:myuser/myproject.git`), it asks me for a password.

I triple checked, my ssh key configuration is correct.

I left the `gitlab.rb` config by default, except for this line:

```
external_url 'https://example.com'
```

What happens here?

Comment: Just a note ... it is normal to have to enter a password for ssh when the key is protected by a passphrase. So you may want to check this (credential managers can alter this behavior - if you are using one. For instance, on my windows machines I usually do have to enter my ssh password when I startup and use my shell for the first time).

Comment: I'm using linux and for this particular key, I don't use a passphrase. And I really don't know the password of the "git" user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For this particular key, I don't use a passphrase

That means SSH fails to connect to `example.com` as `git`, and falls back to the Identity authentication: `git`'s password (which you are not supposed to have).

Using a port syntax `HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT`, you are supposed to launched your GitLab Docker container with a host port (for instance 2222) mapped to GitLab internal SSH daemon (port 22)

```
sudo docker run [...] -port 2222:22
```

Then check it is working with:

```bash
ssh -T git@example.com -p 2222
Welcome to GitLab, @you!
```

With a `~/.ssh/config` file, it is easier:

```
Host         gl
hostname     example.com
port         2222
User         git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yourGitLabkey
```

Then:

```bash
ssh -T gh
Welcome to GitLab, @you!
```

See as examples [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/doker-reverse-proxy-port-22-ssh/68299/2), or [this thread](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/unable-to-connect-to-gitlab-docker-container-via-ssh/51915/3), based on the official documentation "[Install GitLab using Docker Compose](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/install/docker.html#install-gitlab-using-docker-compose)", mentioned by [issue 1767](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/-/issues/1767#note_602896187).